# Вставить данные в БД SQLite3

Tags: c++, sql, sqlite, sqlite3

Каким образом происходит запись данных(`int`, `long long`, `double`) в `sqlite3`?

Собственно с записью значений типа `string` мне удалось разобраться:

```
 sqlite3_stmt *stmt;
 sqlite3* db;

 int rc;             // return code
 char *errmsg;       // pointer to an error string
 //open out db

 rc = sqlite3_open(nameDB.c_str(), &db);
 //to answer on our request to open
 char* request_status = 0;


 if (rc != SQLITE_OK) {
     printf("ERROR opening SQLite DB: %s\n", sqlite3_errmsg(db));
     goto out;
 }
 printf("opened SQLite handle successfully.\n");
 //create sql request (create columns)
 statistic_query = "CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS  MY_TABLE(uno, dos, tres)";
 //compiling request  
 sqlite3_prepare_v2(db, statistic_query.c_str(), strlen(statistic_query.c_str()), &stmt, NULL);
 //send sql request to database
 rc = sqlite3_step(stmt);

 //and now create sql request with our data
  statistic_query = "INSERT INTO MY_TABLE(uno, dos, tres) VALUES (string1,sting2, string3);";
  sqlite3_prepare_v2(db, statistic_query.c_str(), strlen(statistic_query.c_str()), &stmt, NULL);

  rc = sqlite3_step(stmt);
         if (rc != SQLITE_DONE)
         {
             printf("ERROR inserting data: %s\n", sqlite3_errmsg(db));
             goto out;
         }
         sqlite3_finalize(stmt);
```

То есть таким образом можно сформировать строку из значений типа `string` для sql запроса.

Вопрос как в одну строку в БД записать разные значений(1 столбец =`int`, 2 столбец `long long`, 3 столбец `double`).

Для записи различных типов sqlite имеет соответствующие функции:

long long: `int sqlite3_bind_int64(sqlite3_stmt*, int, long long int);`

double: `int sqlite3_bind_double(sqlite3_stmt*, int, double);`

int: `int sqlite3_bind_int(sqlite3_stmt*, int, int);`

Но мне не очень понятно, как с помощью данных функций реализовать мою задачу. 
(p.s.: так же второй вопрос, каким образом можно задать соответствующие типы 
 ячеек?).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Собственно разобрался, ответ нашел на официальном сайте:

https://sqlite.org/datatype3.html

> SQL database engines that use rigid typing will usually try to automatically convert values to the appropriate datatype.
>
> Consider this:
>   CREATE TABLE t1(a INT, b VARCHAR(10));
>
> INSERT INTO t1(a,b) VALUES('123',456);
>
> Rigidly-typed database will convert the string '123' into an integer 123 and 
>   the integer 456 into a string '456' prior to doing the insert.

То есть, SQLite автоматически преобразовывает значения при записи и чтении в возможный формат.

И это действительно работает.